# Are there any prerequisites to wielding Mjolnir in supernatural

Tags: supernatural, mythology, mjolnir

I know Mjolnir has been [done to death](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=Mjolnir) on this site, but I've just seen Sam Winchester smash in some supernatural faces with Mjolnir. Does Mjolnir have the same requirements for use in the supernatural universe?

Now, I realise this is the first instance we've seen it, but I also know Supernatural *tends* to stick to myth. So the real question is: Are there any requirements for using Mjolnir in norse myth, that supernatural might observe?

Comment: Are we considering wielding and lifting to be the same thing here? There don't seem to be any restrictions on lifting it in the show, since at least two people (Sam and the man who won it in the auction) are seen carrying it in that episode, though only one of them actually uses it as a weapon.

Comment: @anthonygrist It's worth addressing, but if we find no differentiation, then we find none.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the original Norse mythology describing Mjölnir's origins, there are no restrictions on who can wield it. Marvel's creation story behind Mjölnir (the first one, *not* the later "fallen star" background used in the movies) otherwise follows the most popular version of the Norse myth relatively closely.

Mjölnir was the result of a contest between Loki and two dwarves, to see if they could create gifts for Asgard that were better than those the gods already possessed. Loki, of course, tried to cheat by interrupting their work but only succeeded with Mjölnir, causing the handle to be too short to be wielded two-handed. This made it hard for anyone lacking god-like strength to wield it, but otherwise there were no real limitations as to *who* could wield it. (As a side note - Loki lost, and had his mouth sewn shut as a result.)

In a lot of later Thor myths, he does possess a special belt and gloves - the belt doubles his strength and the gloves permit him to wield Mjölnir one-handed. The three items together are considered Thor's most prized possessions, but they are not restricted to Thor alone. There are several stories of mythological beings such as giants stealing Thor's posessions and Thor having to go get them back.

Comment: So Sam wielding it is no big deal?

Comment: Not by the classic mythological standards, it was just a very heavy, short-handled, well designed, signature weapon.

Comment: @Pureferret Not as such, though I don't know that Mjölnir had ever been wielded by a mortal in myth. Other than Thor, most other beings that have carried it were supernatural (dwarves, giants, other gods), but its also the kind of thing a Norse mortal would probably not even consider an option.

Comment: You have to wonder whether Sam and Dean would even be considered mortal (in the same way that a random extra in the show would be) at this point - while they no doubt *can* die, it wouldn't be anywhere close to the first time for either of them.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist they certainly have a few up on Buffy.

Answer (score 1):

In the stories I've heard of Mjolnir; Thor is the only one strong enough to lift it. So I guess there aren't any prerequisites, you just have to be as strong as Thor (but by the "fine print" Thor is the strongest person in the universe.)

Answer (score -2):

In the comics I believe that Odin is the one who put that specific enchantment on Mjolnir; the one which prevents anyone not pure of heart from lifting it. If Supernatural follows the Marvel Comics mythology, the enchantment Odin put on Mjolnir might be void because Odin is dead. I wonder if Thor will seek vengeance.

Comment: Supernatural is not related to the Marvel universe...

Comment: I thought I had clearly precluded Marvel from the question. This answer isn't of much use as the two universes aren't at all related.

Comment: That being said I'm not sure if the mythology follows the same logic...

Answer (score -2):

If you are referring to the prerequisites in the Marvel cinematic universe, then I have a theory. The theory is that maybe since Mjolnir is being auctioned off, then Thor is dead, and there is no power of Thor to wield Mjolnir. If this is so, then maybe the prerequisites of wielding the hammer are no longer in tact. This would explain why Sam and the Old Guy could wield Mjolnir.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with marvel.

Comment: Also, please back up theories with some sort of evidence when answering.

Answer (score -3):

The original mythology states that Thor is ONLY one who can lift Mjölnir (even Odin is unable to wield it).  The only other Norse god who could lift Mjölnir was Thor's son Magni ("Might").  Also, the original Mjölnir never states the comic reference of "he be worthy".

Comment: Considering that perhaps the most famous myth about Mjølner is of when Trym stole it, this answer is obviously wrong.